# Expression/word combination for "object of application"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, expression-choice

I need to be able to refer to an object which has/needs something applied to it or used on it. A couple of examples:

- one liter of paint is needed to paint an **area** of 10m².
- 6 birthday candles are needed to decorate a **birthday cake.**
- 1000 bricks are enough to lay a 100m long **pavement** track.

What I'm trying to describe here is : area, birthday cake, pavement.

The best I've come up with is 'object of application'. I looked it up on Google, and it mostly refers to terms in objective programming, so that wasn't a great deal of help.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What about: unit of application?

Comment: There already is a variable named 'units' - units of measurements (liters, meters, etc.), so naming something 'unit' again would cause unnecessary ambiguity. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word which linguistics/grammar uses for this is *patient*:

> **patient** *Linguistics* The semantic role of a noun phrase denoting something that is affected or acted upon by the action of a verb. [[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/patient?q=patient)]

...that is, "something which receives an action".

Comment: Although not very technical, I believe that this word best fits the description.

Answer (score 1):

"Target area" or just "target" might work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *substrate.* OED:

> <sup>*n*</sup>1. A thing which underlies or forms the basis of another; a substratum, a foundation. Freq. *fig.*
>
> . . .
>
> <sup>*n*</sup>5. *Materials Sci.* Any bulk phase or material to which a film, coating, etc., is applied.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for.